# Expresso Store: Pre-populate a cart with a members last order

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Basically I'm looking for a way to allow logged in users to re-order their last order. Has anyone ever tried this before in Expresso Store?

Comment: Haven't tried that before, but just thinking. Could you make {exp:store:checkout} and within that populate the products?

Comment: Yes I was just thinking the same thing. Use the users last order items loop and create the update quantities fields in the checkout form tag. Would be cool if there was an order_id parameter for the checkout tag though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to do it. There are lots of possible complexities, like the fact products ordered in the past may no longer even exist!

If you want to do this, two possible ways come to mind.

You could use the standard add to cart tag along with the orders tag, to add multiple products from a previous order to the cart, all at once. This would require some clever templating, especially if your products have complex modifiers.

Alternatively, you could use PHP and create a simple plugin, which loads a previous order and adds products to the current cart. This would probably be cleaner, but requires some knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Adrian. Yeah, I understand the complexities of including a native way to do this from within Store. Fortunately, the project I'm working on doesn't have the need for product modifiers so that may simplify some things. I'll post what I come up with in the end.